# How to get desktop notifications of Evolution in Mint

Tags: mate-desktop, notifications, evolution, mail-user-agent

I've got problems setting up the notifications for Evolution. I already installed `mail-indicator-evolution` and `evolution-indicator` but neither of them appear in the notification area.

How can I properly set it up? Besides, I'd like the mail to be updated automatically without a window open.

I'm using the MATE desktop environment.

Answer (score 2):

open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y evolution-plugins`.
this should do the trick for the notifications while evolution is open... maybe you have to configure/activate/deactivate some of these plugins in *Evolution* via *Edit*, *Plugins*.

---

if you want a notification without evolution running in the background, open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y mail-notification-evolution`.
this will install a little extra program checking for mails in the background without having the mail-client running. maybe you just have to configure it to your needs via the launcher in the control center.